# How can I compute expected return time of a state in a Markov Chain?

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I was watching a YouTube video regarding the calculation of expected return time of a Markov Chain.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_Ll0-Ytu7U&vl=en

I haven't understood the calculation of $m_{12}$.

[image]

How could he write $m_{12} = 1+ p_{11}m_{12}$?

Why is $m_{12}$ on the both side of the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept the first equation laid out, that is,
$$
m_{ij} = 1 p_{ij} + \sum_{k\neq j}p_{ik}(1 + m_{kj})
$$
then,
$$
m_{12} = 1 + \sum_{k\neq 2}p_{1k}m_{k2}
$$
and since we have just the two states it follows that this is,
$$
m_{12} = 1 +p_{11}m_{12} = 1 + (0.9)m_{12}
$$
so can you see that solving gives $m_{12}=10$? It really just follows from that first equation, then simple algebra.

Comment: Why didn't he add 1 in case of $m_{11}$?

Comment: if i=j, like in the case of $m_{11}$, then note the relation in the top right corner ($m_{11}=1/ \pi_1$). I'm not sure what the video discussed but there is a mean recurrence time theorem that gives us that this is the case for an irreducible Markov chain.